# Where is the "documentation"?

Tags: documentation, reledmac

I got many errors and ... "See the reledmac package documentation for explanation". Where is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288267/does-texlive-comes-with-documentations-of-packages (BTW: The new `texdoc` from TeX Live 2023 also allows searching on texdoc.org.)

Comment: The answer in the referred question isn’t up-to-date anymore. MikTeX installs a lot of packages in two steps: it adds the `*.sty` file the usual way, but you have to check the `Documentation` tab to check whether the `*.pdf` is also installed. Especially when you install packages on the fly, only the `*.sty` is installed.